# taking page snapshot javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In google plus, when you click on the send feedback button located on the bottom-right corner, it enables us to highlight the area where the error has occurred. When we highlight the area and click on submit, the page snapshot is saved for the developers of gplus for the reference to the complain. I want to develop a similar bug tracker using which, i can enable my users to send the snapshot of the page they have faced the error. I want to do that using php as backend.

Comment: javascript is used only to get the cordinates of selected area .

Comment: you mean to say that those coordinates are then used to generate image on backend??

Comment: yes indeed since the request was send to the server prior to showing the thumbnail .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with HTML5 + Canvas + JavaScript.
Google "HTML5 screenshot" :)

http://hertzen.com/experiments/jsfeedback/

Comment: In this code, it is using html canvas which is not supported by <IE9. But google plus' that function is supported by IE 7 and 8 too. There must be some other way.. But still, its usefull.